# How to train a CNN to decode a multi length captcha

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Hi I'm a beginner in image classification . My task is to decode captcha's using a simple keras deep learning model. I chose a simple convolutional neural network at the beginning which is giving me good accuracy as far my length of the captcha is fixed to 6. But the moment I have a 5 letter captcha, the accuracy is bad. The model forcefully predicts the 6th even in the absense. How should I tackle this? Please help.

Some of the question coming to my mind are :

1. Can we have multiple output layer at the end?
2. Is it possible to pre-process the data for this model without mentioning the Max length of the captcha ?
3. I have seen a couple of sites with recurrent neural networks layers over the CNN model. But as a beginner, it was extremely confusing. Is this a good solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem ideally boils down to recognizing multiple letters of the captcha wherein the captcha can have any number of letters. You can use Yolo as also suggested by [How to Recognise multiple objects in the same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364513/how-to-recognise-multiple-objects-in-the-same-image)

If you would want to proceed as you have mentioned, you can make a model first to detect the number of letters in the captcha and then proceed to decode the multi length captcha

Comment: Or you can specify the fixed length of Captcha (ex.15 characters) and then read it (as long as it is) and pad the rest of the sequence (15 - length of captcha) with some neutral symbol that you'll know you have to remove in the postprocessing (like '/')

Comment: Thank you so much @Manmeet. Your answer makes a lot of sense but for the latter part do you think I have to train the network with individual letter images or will it be like I will just have to reshape the output according to the num of letters detected by the yolo network ?

Comment: Thank you for response @Novak. Your approach seems interesting , I'll definitey try this and get back to you.

Comment: @user1896293 You can use a standard mnist classifier to detect the letters and then use yolo for identifying letters in the captcha.

Comment: Thank you @ManmeetSingh planning to try your approach as well